# Merging Visual Studio solution files

Tags: windows, ide

Is there a tool to merge several Visual Studio solution files (.sln) to a single solution file?

Must have:

- merging the projects (.csproj)
- merging solution folders
- If it does not offer merging configurations (Debug, Release, Trial Debug, Trial Release, ...), it should at least provide the option to choose a configuration of one of the solutions.

Nice to have:

- merging the build order / project dependencies

Please don't provide answers for general purpose merge tools such as WinMerge, BeyondCompare or Code Compare.

Budget: ~30€, gratis preferred of course

---

*Background information*

I don't exactly know why we have several solution files in our projects, but it happens except for very small projects. Maybe it's because developers want to reduce startup time of Visual Studio or compile time. This organizational issue is another topic I am working on. Maybe there's just no definition for it.

For me it's important to have a complete solution containing all projects, because:

- I want to turn on R# solution wide analysis
- I want to do NDepend analysis

and both works best if all projects are part of the solution and can be compiled.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you add some context, i.e. tell us *why* you need this?

Comment: @Jeroen: I have added context information to the question.